# How to add Buy Now button in cs-cart

Tags: php, cs-cart

I'm creating a buy-now button cs-cart add-on. I've created an add-on and I've made the add-to-cart functionality work. But cant redirect it to checkout page. I have used "fn_redirect("checkout")" function for the redirection. And used this function below this:

```
"fn_add_product_to_cart($_REQUEST['product_data'], $cart, $auth);"
```

What should I do for redirection?

Edit: 
 My controller (buy_now.php)

```
if ($mode == 'add') {

    if (empty($auth['user_id']) && Registry::get('settings.General.allow_anonymous_shopping') != 'allow_shopping')
     {
        return array(CONTROLLER_STATUS_REDIRECT, "auth.login_form?return_url=" . urlencode($_REQUEST['return_url']));
    }



    // Add to cart button was pressed for single product on advanced list
    if (!empty($dispatch_extra)) {
        if (empty($_REQUEST['product_data'][$dispatch_extra]['amount'])) {
            $_REQUEST['product_data'][$dispatch_extra]['amount'] = 1;
        }
        foreach ($_REQUEST['product_data'] as $key => $data) {
            if ($key != $dispatch_extra && $key != 'custom_files') {
                unset($_REQUEST['product_data'][$key]);
            }
        }
    }



    $prev_cart_products = empty($cart['products']) ? array() : $cart['products'];

    fn_add_product_to_cart($_REQUEST['product_data'], $cart, $auth);

    fn_save_cart_content($cart, $auth['user_id']);


   $previous_state = md5(serialize($cart['products']));
    $cart['change_cart_products'] = true;
    fn_calculate_cart_content($cart, $auth, 'S', true, 'F', true);



    if (md5(serialize($cart['products'])) != $previous_state && empty($cart['skip_notification'])) {
        $product_cnt = 0;
        $added_products = array();


        if (!empty($added_products)) {
            Registry::get('view')->assign('added_products', $added_products);

            if (Registry::get('config.tweaks.disable_dhtml') && Registry::get('config.tweaks.redirect_to_cart')) {
                Registry::get('view')->assign('continue_url', (!empty($_REQUEST['redirect_url']) && empty($_REQUEST['appearance']['details_page'])) ? $_REQUEST['redirect_url'] : $_SESSION['continue_url']);

               }


             fn_redirect(Registry::get('config.https_location') . "/checkout");
          // $msg = Registry::get('view')->fetch('views/checkout/components/product_notification.tpl');

           //fn_set_notification('I', __($product_cnt > 1 ? 'products_added_to_cart' : 'product_added_to_cart'), $msg, 'I');
            $cart['recalculate'] = true;
        } else {
            fn_set_notification('N', __('notice'), __('product_in_cart'));
        }
    }

    unset($cart['skip_notification']);

    $_suffix = '.checkout';
}
```

`

hook template : add_to_cart.post.tpl

```
{$id = "buy_now_{$product.product_id}"}
<button id="opener_{$id}" name="dispatch[buy_now.add..{$product.product_id}]"  class=" vs-button buynow_btn_">Buy Now</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd consider putting your fn_redirect("checkout") code into an if/else statement to see what's happening with it.

If you have this code:

```
    fn_add_product_to_cart($_REQUEST['product_data'], $cart, $auth);
```

Then surely you can put the redirection to the checkout page underneath it?

```
    $redirect_url = "http://testcheckout.com?test=test"; //change this!
    $errorMessage = "I should have redirected already....";
    if (!empty($redirect_url)) {
        //if it's not empty then it should redirect.
        fn_redirect($redirect_url);

       //Then put a die statement in here just to check it's not executing
       //anything else and you can see if the redirect has a problem: 
       die(print_r($errorMessage, true ));
    } 
    else {
        //otherwise there is a problem with the supplied redirect url (empty)
        die(print_r($redirect_url, true ));
    }
```

I'd also take a look at this page which might help more:

http://forum.cs-cart.com/topic/6873-direct-buy-button/

Hope that helps!

Comment: Its not printing anything. just added the product to the cart .

Comment: If you put the  die(print_r($errorMessage, true )); prior to the add to cart function does it print out anything?

Comment: Any other method for redirection?

Comment: Could you post some more of the code that you have in your answer? Without seeing more of what you've tried it's hard to offer up anything that will work with your implementation

Comment: I've had another look, and I'm not really sure how to do it without doing some further testing. I'd suggest posting your question here: http://forum.cs-cart.com/ - sorry I can't be more helpful to you!